# Can I get a peek at a deleted answer

Tags: support

[Sending authentication with WebBrowser control and proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143762/sending-authentication-with-webbrowser-control-and-proxy)

I don't know the history of this post, but the user which posted the answer has put a comment saying that his answer got deleted for some reason + He also claims that it is an answer to the question.

Please treat this as a one-off request. I suppose the content can be shared here (as an answer to this post) if possible and not on the main site. Just for perusal purposes.

Comment: The deleted answer says: "have you tried setting the username and password in the actual URL? that might work, let me know if it does/doesn't."  ...That's all.

Comment: @wim: I'd flag that answer in an instant.

Answer (score 3):

You get access to deleted posts at [10k rep.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

Don't post requests like these. They're off-topic to meta.
Instead, just ask the user to provide a summary of his answer in a comment, or to write a better answer.

---

I just noticed how damn ***old*** that post was.

Commenting, asking for the answer to be re-posted would probably have been pointless, since the guy that posted it hasn't been active since *August 29, 2014*.
In this case, you'd be best off searching for different answers.

Comment: Side-note: the answer _was_ bad. You probably replaced your actual username / password in your code, so you can post it on meta, and the guy told you those wouldn't work.